# the procs avg and IsZugi doesn't work in my assembly code

Tags: assembly

thank you very much for helping me, I have done all the changes, as you can see below. however, yet it does not work... :(
I might have done something wrong, would you mind taking another pick?
thank you for all you have done!

I forgot to mention that I created a few arrays if it makes any differens...
    ArrayA dw  9 dup(0)
    ArrayB dw  9 dup(0)
    ArrayC dw  9 dup(0)

`proc    Part2 
    GoAgain:    mov ah, 1   ;receives a number 
            int 21h
            cmp al,65   ;checks if A
            jne TryNext
            call PrintA
            jmp GoAgain
    TryNext:cmp al,66   ;checks if B
            jne TryNext2
            call PrintB
            jmp GoAgain
    TryNext2:   cmp al,67   ;checks if C
            jne TryNext3
            call PrintC
            jmp GoAgain
    TryNext3:   cmp al,69   ;checks if E
            jne TryNext4
            push offset counter
            call IsZugi
            jmp GoAgain
    TryNext4:   cmp al,80   ;checks if P
            jne TryNext5
            push offset counter
            call IsZugi
            jmp GoAgain
    TryNext5:   cmp al,86
            jne TryNext6
            push offset counter
            call avg
            jmp GoAgain
    TryNext6:   cmp al,'#'
            jne TryAgain
            ret
    TryAgain:mov dx, offset message2
            mov ah, 9h 
            int 21h
            jmp GoAgain
            ret
    endp    Part2
    proc    PrintA
            mov dl,'a'
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            mov bx,0
    again:  cmp [bx],0  ;checks if index isnt empty
            jne NotEnd2
            ret
    NotEnd2:mov dl,' ' ;print space
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            mov ax,[word ptr bx]
            add al,30h
            mov dl,al;print the number
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            inc bx  ;goes to the next index
            jmp again
            ret
    endp    PrintA
    proc    PrintB
            mov dl,'b'
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            mov bx,10
    again2: cmp [bx],0  ;checks if index isnt empty
            jne NotEnd2
            ret
    NotEnd3:mov dl,' ' ;print space
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            mov ax,[word ptr bx]
            add al,30h
            mov dl,al;print the number
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            inc bx  ;goes to the next index
            jmp again
            ret
    endp    PrintB
    proc    PrintC
            mov dl,'c'
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            mov bx,20
    again3: cmp [bx],0  ;checks if index isnt empty
            jne NotEnd2
            ret
    NotEnd4:mov dl,' ' ;print space
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            mov ax,[word ptr bx]
            add al,30h
            mov dl,al;print the number
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            inc bx  ;goes to the next index
            jmp again
            ret
    endp    PrintC
    proc    IsZugi
            pop [ReturnAddress]
            pop si;counter
            mov dx,0
            mov bx,0;the beginning
    redo:   mov ax,2;to check if number%2=0
            mov dx,0
            mov cx,[bx];cx=number
            cmp cx,0;checks if index=null
            je  next;all the array was read
            mov di,ax
            mov ax,cx
            mov cx,di
            div cx;number/2
            inc bx
            cmp dx,0;to check if number%2=0
            jne redo;go to the next index
            inc [word ptr si];inc counter
            jmp redo
    next:   inc dx
            cmp dx,2
            ja  LastArray
            mov bx,10;moves to the second array
            jmp redo
    LastArray:  cmp dx,3
                je  done
                mov bx,29;moves to the last array
                jmp redo
    done:   mov dl,'P';print p
            mov ah, 2h 
            int 21h
            mov dl,' ';print space
            mov ah, 2h 
            int 21h
            mov al,[byte ptr si]
            add al,30h
            mov dl,al;print the counter
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            mov dl,'E';print e
            mov ah, 2h 
            int 21h
            mov dl,' ';print space
            mov ah, 2h
            int 21h
            mov cl,[byte ptr si]
            mov ch,9
            sub ch,cl
            add ch,30h
            mov dl,ch;print the 9-counter
            int 21h
            push [ReturnAddress]`

```
        ret
endp    IsZugi
proc    IsLegal 
        mov bx,0
        pop [ReturnAddress]
        pop ax  ;receives the number
        cmp ax, 8   ;checks if belongs to A
        jb  B
occupied?:
        cmp [word ptr bx],0;occupied or not
        je  NotOccupied
        inc bx
        jmp occupied?
NotOccupied:
        mov [bx],ax ;enters the number to it's place
        jmp finish
B:      cmp ax,6    ;checks if belongs to B
        jb CC
        add bx,10   ;moves to the next array
occupied2?: cmp [word ptr bx],0 ;checks if index occupied
        je  NotOccupied2
        inc bx  ;checks next index
        jmp occupied2?
NotOccupied2:   mov [bx],ax ;enters the value to it's array
        jmp finish
CC:     add bx,20   ;the beginning of the next array  
occupied3?: cmp [word ptr bx],0 ;checks if empty
        je  NotOccupied3
        inc bx  ;checks next index
        jmp occupied3?
NotOccupied3:
        mov [bx],ax ;enters the value to it's array
finish: cmp ax,9    ;checks if legal
        ja FalseExit        ;if illegal exit 
        cmp ax,0    ;checks if legal
        jl FalseExit        ;if illegal exit
        push 0      ;since we poped ax
        push [ReturnAddress]
        ret
endp    IsLegal
proc    avg
        pop [ReturnAddress]
        mov bx,0    ;first index
        pop si      ;si=sum
suming: mov ax,[word ptr si]    ;it's impossible to do- mov [si],[bx] so...
        add ax,[bx];sum+=bx
        mov [word ptr si],ax
        inc bx
        cmp bx,29
        jne suming
        mov dx, offset message  ;print avg
        mov ah, 9h 
        int 21h 
        mov ax,[word ptr si]
        mov [word ptr si],9
        div ax
        add al,30h
        mov dl,al
        mov ah,2
        int 21h
        push 0
        push [ReturnAddress]
        ret
endp    avg
start:  
        jmp TrueStart
FalseExit:  jmp exit        
TrueStart:  mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax
        mov cx,9    ;loop*9
zloop:  mov ah, 1   ;receives a number 
        int 21h
        sub al,30h  ;reveal the real number
        mov ah,0    ;we only need al, however we can only push word
        push ax     ;pushes the number
        call IsLegal
        ;loop zloop
        push offset sum
        call avg
        push offset counter
        ;call IsZugi
        ;call PrintA
        ;call PrintB
        ;call PrintC
        ;call Part2
        call Creative
```

<\code>

Comment: Please don't change the question the way you did with info you got from the answer!

Comment: At the very least upvote this answer - __that clearly helped you already!__ - before asking the same question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proc    IsZugi
    pop [ReturnAddress]
    pop si;counter
```

Each time you call *IsZugi* there no mention of an extra argument. So where do get the `pop si` from?
Also the comment `;counter` is misleading since it seems to be the address of a counter.

```
TryNext3:   cmp al,69   ;checks if E
    jne TryNext4
    push offset counter      <<< add this
    call IsZugi
    jmp GoAgain
TryNext4:   cmp al,80   ;checks if P
    jne TryNext5
    push offset counter      <<< add this
    call IsZugi
    jmp GoAgain
TryNext5:   cmp al,86
    jne TryNext6
    push offset counter      <<< add this
    call avg
    jmp GoAgain
```

---

```
        mov dx,0
        mov bx,0;the beginning
redo:   mov ax,2;to check if number%2=0
```

You need to repeat the `mov dx,0` with each *redo* to get a correct division.

```
        mov bx,0;the beginning
redo:   mov ax,2;to check if number%2=0
        mov dx,0
```

---

```
div cx;number/2
inc bx
cmp ah,0;to check if number%2=0
```

Since you've done a **word** division you have to check for any remainder in the `DX` register, not in the `AH` register!

Comment: At the very least upvote this answer - __that clearly helped you already!__ - before asking the same question again.